# Not able to display from controller to view in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Hi I'm Trying to display results from controller to view in Codeigniter. I fetching the results from model to controller and then displaying the details to map and inside div.

I'm using biostall for displaying on map.It is working perfectly.Also i  want to display inside div also which is not working. Here is my Code..

My Model Code..

```
function getRegaddress($citycheck,$lat,$lng,$itemid,$hotelid) {
     $return =array();
    // Here goes Query....

    //$query = mysql_query($results);

    if ($query->num_rows() >0) {

        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            array_push($return, $row);
        }
            // return $query->result();

        }

        return $return;
    }
}
```

Here The Controller code

```
$data = $this->maps_model->getRegaddress($citycheck,$lat,$lng,$itemid,$hotelid);

$data['hotelname'] = $hotelname;

$config['center'] =  $lat.",".$lng;

$this->load->library('googlemaps');

$this->googlemaps->initialize($config);

foreach ($data as $coordinate) {

    //  $data = array();

    //  $data['values']=$coordinate->hotelname;

    $marker = array();
    $marker['title'] = $coordinate->hotelname;
    $marker['position'] = $coordinate->lat.','.$coordinate->lng;

    $this->googlemaps->add_marker($marker);
}

$data = array();

$data['map'] = $this->googlemaps->create_map();
$this->load->view('templates/_header');
$this->load->view('content/temp-view', $data);
$this->load->view('templates/footer');
```

View Code

```
<?php echo $map['js']; ?>

<div class="col-lg-8">
<div class="media"><a href="menu/"> </a>                        
<h3 class="media-heading text-danger-theme"><?php echo $hotelname; ?></h3>
<?php echo $map['html']; ?>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

In the result ... The map marker is showing the details from database. But When I display the delalername on the div it is showing an error like ...

```
Severity: Notice
Message: Trying to get property of non-object
Filename: controllers/mapcontrol.php
Line Number: 84
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Notice
Message: Trying to get property of non-object
Filename: controllers/mapcontrol.php
Line Number: 84
```

Why i'm getting this error? Anyone Knows Please Help ...

Here is the structure of output

```
array(3) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#23 (15) { ["hotelid"]=> string(1) "2" ["hoteltype"]=> string(1) "3" ["hotelname"]=> string(18) "Sreekrishna food" ["dealerloc"]=> string(27) "Bengaluru, Karnataka, India" ["lat"]=> string(18) "12.971598700000000" ["lng"]=> string(18) "77.594562699999980" ["dealercity"]=> string(9) "Bengaluru" ["dealeraddress"]=> string(27) "Bengaluru, Karnataka, India" ["type"]=> string(2) "ar" ["stype"]=> string(3) "ggs" ["email"]=> string(15) "local@gmail.com" ["mobile"]=> string(10) "9947485214" ["phone"]=> string(10) "9947485214" ["website"]=> string(0) "" ["distance"]=> string(22) "0.00005899369716644287" } [1]=> object(stdClass)#24 (15) { ["hotelid"]=> string(1) "3" ["hoteltype"]=> string(1) "3" ["hotelname"]=> string(15) "Aey food" ["dealerloc"]=> string(42) "Shivaji Nagar, Bengaluru, Karnataka, India" ["lat"]=> string(18) "12.985650300000000" ["lng"]=> string(18) "77.605692699999960" ["dealercity"]=> string(13) "Shivaji Nagar" ["dealeraddress"]=> string(42) "Shivaji Nagar, Bengaluru, Karnataka, India" ["type"]=> string(2) "ar" ["stype"]=> string(3) "ggs" ["email"]=> string(9) "std@ff.il" ["mobile"]=> string(10) "9947485214" ["phone"]=> string(10) "9947485214" ["website"]=> string(0) "" ["distance"]=> string(18) "1.2265085392649464" } [2]=> object(stdClass)#25 (15) { ["hotelid"]=> string(1) "1" ["hoteltype"]=> string(1) "3" ["hotelname"]=> string(17) "Super - foods" ["dealerloc"]=> string(47) "FM Cariappa Colony, Bengaluru, Karnataka, India" ["lat"]=> string(18) "12.977923000000000" ["lng"]=> string(18) "77.612083499999930" ["dealercity"]=> string(18) "FM Cariappa Colony" ["dealeraddress"]=> string(47) "FM Cariappa Colony, Bengaluru, Karnataka, India" ["type"]=> string(2) "ar" ["stype"]=> string(3) "ggs" ["email"]=> string(11) "ddd@gfgf.in" ["mobile"]=> string(10) "9947485214" ["phone"]=> string(10) "9947485214" ["website"]=> string(12) "www.music.in" ["distance"]=> string(18) "1.2580702750661623" } }
```

Comment: Just a note if your using codeigniter 3 and above make filename of controller Mapcontrol.php instead of mapcontrol.php as per the user guide [here](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/controllers.html#let-s-try-it-hello-world)

Comment: i,ve changed..still showing error

Comment: Which one is line 84?

Comment: $marker['position'] = $coordinate->lat.','.$coordinate->lng;

Comment: For displaying marker on map $marker is necessary

Comment: You are unnecessarely modifying query result in model. Just make it `if ($query->num_rows() > 0){return $query->result();}//$query->result_array() if prefered`.

Comment: Already tried that code ..But didnt worked

Comment: After proposal, `$data = $this->maps_model->getRegaddress($citycheck,$lat,$lng,$itemid,$hotelid);var_dump($data);exit;` What is the output?

Comment: Showing the list of selected values from database as an array according to query

Comment: You are requesting lat and lon in controller arguments. What are those if you want more than one hotel returned from DB?

Comment: to display on maps ... the problem is i'm able to display on maps but when i'm about to print hotelname inside a div it shows the error.

Comment: My question is what lat/lon you pass to controller? Particular hotel or something else?

Comment: coordinate positions  For eg;$lat=12.9667;
     $lng=77.5667;

Comment: Because on return you get 3 hotels from DB. How can 3 hotels be related to same particular lat/lon?

Comment: no.. they are of different lat and long ie 3 of them are of from different coordinates and they are nearby places with in 2.5km

Comment: actually they dont have any relationship with error since the details are getting and printing on map successfully at different coordinates. The error is not able to print inside div

Comment: You have to debug your code line by line to see what values you get from variables you want to use. I.e. before foreach loop var_dump($data) to see the correct way you are suppose to pick lat and lon. Also you shouldn't (re)assign properties before you have all members needed for loop/output, especially if you don't debug code to see variables' values. I would need more code to help you since this is likely changed from point we started conversation.This part doesn't look correct neither`$data['hotelname'] = $hotelname;`.`$hotelname` should be set variable for this work.Where is it set before?

Comment: Also, maybe error is because you are mixing `$data` returned from model and rest of `$data` array intended to be passed to view.